# Is it possible to unset the WHEN condition on a Snowflake task?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an existing Snowflake task that is scheduled to run once an hour and is using the **WHEN** condition to check if a particular stream has data. I'd like to [ALTER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-task.html) this task so that it no longer uses the when condition, however, **unset** does not seem to work and I cannot **modify** it to NULL. The one workaround we've found is you can modify it to TRUE which seems to work (the statement executes and the task does run), but I'd prefer to have it unset like the other tasks that do not have a when condition set. I also recognize I could drop the task and recreate it, however, then I'd lose the history. This is not a significant problem, but seems strange that it cannot be modified after the fact and I've not seen any documentation that indicates this is expected behavior.

Note: I've made sure the [root task is suspended](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-task.html#usage-notes) before trying to make any changes.

```
alter task example_task unset when;
```

> SQL compilation error: invalid property 'when' for 'TASK'

```
alter task example_task modify when NULL;
```

> Invalid expression for task condition expression. Expecting one of
> the following: [SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA]

```
alter task example_task unset condition;
```

> SQL compilation error: invalid property 'condition' for 'TASK'

(Note: tested ^ because the column is labeled 'condition' when you run **show tasks**)

```
alter task example_task remove when;
```

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 31 unexpected
> 'when'.

(Note: tested ^ because you use 'remove' to change the 'after' parameter)

```
alter task example_task modify when TRUE;
```

> Statement executed successfully.

As a side note, this came to our attention while trying to use the [snowflake terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/chanzuckerberg/snowflake/latest) which unsuccessfully tried to update the when condition. Now I think I know why.

Comment: Thanks to @NickW's response and some additional testing it looks like my concerns around losing the task history are unfounded as that is maintained separately in information_schema.task_history. So then a followup question is **are there any downsides to simply dropping/recreating the task?**

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, why not replace the whole task using CREATE OR REPLACE TASK...?